# Design: android TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

This is my first android application, I face a bunch of problems. I want to make a design like in this image:

[image: desired layout]

I tried many solutions to do it, but nothing work.
This is my code:

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
<View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="@color/dark_blue"/>
        <!--Product information-->
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/product_info">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/product_img"
                       android:src="@drawable/mdpi_product_verify_scan_code"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tvdesc"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_weight="2"
                      android:text="description description description "
                      android:textColor="@color/black"
                    />
        </TableRow>

<View
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="@color/dark_blue"/>

        <!--Images button-->
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Product Description"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    />
            <FrameLayout
                    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|left"
                    android:padding="5dp">
            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/mdpi_btn_show_images_icon"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    />
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Images"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:id="@+id/product_info">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/ima"
                       android:src="@drawable/mdpi_product_verify_scan_code"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_weight="2"
                      android:text="description description description "
                      android:textColor="@color/black"
                    />
        </TableRow>

        <!--Verification -->
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="product verification"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/green"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This product can be verified. Tap on the VERIFY PRODUCT button above."
                    android:textColor="@color/green"/>
        </TableRow>
        
    </TableLayout>
```

and this the result

[image: The result]

as you can see, all the elements are messed up
and the images button disappear also when i set the gravity left the images disappear and the text stay where they are, nothing change.

This image shows what are the problems:
[image: problem markers]

1. How to make each text on a row.
2. Set the image at the left (the gravity left didn't work)
3. How to draw a vertical line?
4. How can i put image with the text?( i was using the span but it's work just for one row here i have two text rows, is there anyway to merge two vertical cells).
5. The images button disappear.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try replacing the TableLayout? Perhaps some combination of RelativeLayout and LinearLayouts/something?

Comment: @Keyser actually no, i'm still not aware with all android design Technics. i saw some tutorials using tablelayout that's why i'm using it.

Comment: Experiment with some others then. There are lots of examples and documentation on the Android Dev site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should help you a bit understand how it works. I manage to do something that looks like what you might need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tap to Verify Product" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try it out in your IDE and from that, if you need further helps, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks, it still has some problems with the images, it don't appear, and there is one text appear correctly like this image shows http://i.imgur.com/DvCK7m0.png?1

Comment: well, for the images you should obviously change the resource file/path. For the text, it's probably some relative layout properties to change.

Comment: changing the image path is first thing i did, for the text i tried to change some properties but it didn't work. anyway i'll try again.

Comment: i didn't change much on the code you wrote, i'm working on it write now, if i couldn't do it right i'll ask you what to do, and thanks for your help. i want to ask you some lame question if you didn't mind is there any tutorial or example for populating the data from the code. some of the pictures and texts in my design above, will be populated from the code, if you give me a link or something will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: http://sree.cc/google/android/android-how-to-add-textview-and-write-text-into-it , pretty simple, but you should really read the http://developer.android.com doc